# pandas groupby events across different days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1,10],[1,2,50],[1,3,20],[1,4,24],
[2,1,20],[2,2,10],[2,3,20],[2,4,34],[3,1,10],[3,2,50],
[3,3,20],[3,4,24],[3,5,24],[4,1,24]],columns=['day','hour','event'])

df
Out[4]: 
    day  hour  event
0     1     1     10
1     1     2     50
2     1     3     20 <- yes
3     1     4     24 <- yes
4     2     1     20 <- yes
5     2     2     10
6     2     3     20 <- yes
7     2     4     34 <- yes
8     3     1     10 <- yes
9     3     2     50
10    3     3     20 <- yes
11    3     4     24 <- yes
11    3     5     24 <- yes (here we have also an hour more)
12    4     1     24 <- yes
```

now I would like to sum the number of events from hour=3 to hour=1 of the following day..

The expected result should be

```
0 64
1 64
2 92
```

Comment: How is 64 getting calculated ? Can't figure out the calculation :(

Comment: I ve added the rows that should be taken into account in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
#convert columns to datetimes, for same day of next day subtract 2 hours:
a = pd.to_datetime(df['day'].astype(str) + ':' + df['hour'].astype(str), format='%d:%H')- pd.Timedelta(2, unit='h')
#get hours between 1 and 23 only ->in real 3,4...23,1
hours = a.dt.hour.between(1,23)
#create consecutives groups by filtering
df['a'] = hours.ne(hours.shift()).cumsum()
#filter only expected hours
df = df[hours]
#aggregate
df = df.groupby('a')['event'].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
0    10
1    64
2    64
3    92
Name: event, dtype: int64
```

---

Another similar solution:

```
#create datetimeindex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['day'].astype(str)+':'+df['hour'].astype(str), format='%d:%H')
#shift by 2 hours 
df = df.shift(-2, freq='h')
#filter hours and first unnecessary event
df = df[(df.index.hour != 0) & (df.index.year != 1899)]
#aggregate
df = df.groupby(df.index.day)['event'].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
0    64
1    64
2    92
Name: event, dtype: int64
```

Another solution:

```
#filter out first values less as 3 and hours == 2
df = df[(df['hour'].eq(3).cumsum() > 0) & (df['hour'] != 2)]
#subtract 1 day by condition and aggregate
df = df['event'].groupby(np.where(df['hour'] < 3, df['day'] - 1, df['day'])).sum()
print (df)
1    64
2    64
3    92
Name: event, dtype: int64
```

Comment: HI, the function pd.to_datetime gives me this error: 
ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: time data 20000100 does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)

Comment: @gabboshow - I create another way for convert to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to just remove all entries for which `hour` is `2`, then combine the results into groups of 3 and sum those;

```
v = df[df.hour != 2][1:].event
np.add.reduceat(v, range(0, len(v), 3))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this solution does not generalize too much...if for one of the day there is an hour more or less it won't work... I ll update the question with a more general case

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define a grouping column via `pd.DataFrame.apply` with a custom function.

Then `groupby` this new column.

```
df['grouping'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['day']-2 if x['hour'] < 3 else x['day']-1, axis=1)

res = df.loc[(df['hour'] != 2) & (df['grouping'] >= 0)]\
        .groupby('grouping')['event'].sum()\
        .reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result**

```
0    64
1    64
2    92
Name: event, dtype: int64
```